# c-generic-library (mallocing several times)

Tags: c, malloc

Navigating through the [c-generic-library](https://code.google.com/archive/p/c-generic-library/) code I found this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include "node.h"
#include "gen/access_macros.h"
#include "gen/error_macros.h"


Node *
construct_Node(size_t nlinks)
{
  Node *ptr = NULL;

  CHECK_VARA(ptr = malloc(sizeof *ptr), NULL);
  if (!(ptr->ptr = malloc(sizeof *(ptr->ptr) * nlinks))) {
    if (!(ptr->ptr = malloc(sizeof *(ptr->ptr) * nlinks))) {
      if (!(ptr->ptr = malloc(sizeof *(ptr->ptr) * nlinks))) {
        return ptr;
      }
    }
  }
  return ptr;
}

void
destruct_Node(Node * node)
{
  free(node->ptr);
  free(node);
}
```

What is the benefit of retrying `malloc` 2 times? I mean, is there any chance that `malloc` will return true if it has already failed twice before?

Comment: If there are other threads and/or other processes running at the same time that also use memory, there is a possibility that some of them can free up some memory. In such a scenario one of the later allocation attempts could succeed, I guess.

Comment: looks weird behavior to return ptr even when failed to allocate memory for ptr->ptr